# RegEX string to specific lengths

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing, split

Hey all I am terrible at RegEX so I am posting this question in hopes that a RegEX Guru will easily know and share the answer.

I have the following string types:

```
508815  AYBK1619RAUEZP
AWBZ4222TYBE1207CWSWER
DEFAULT EP1     O25R60
```

And I am needing it in this format (split):

```
508815   AYBK1619  RAU EZP
AWBZ4222 TYBE1207  CWS WER
DEFAULT  EP1       O25 R60
```

So:
    xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxx xxx

- First 8 characters in string
- Next 8 characters in string
- Next 3 characters in string
- Last 3 characters in string

I can do the Mid(x,x) and all to do that but I figured that using RegEX would be quicker and cleaner looking code.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: If you can't write the regex, then it won't be cleaner code. Stick to what you can understand easily, it'll avoid you headaches in the future.

Comment: @RyanJ Check the updated OP.

Comment: i would not use regex, i would use substring

Comment: Have you done any testing, now that you have a regex, to determine which way is fastest, as you seem to have that as a criterion?

Comment: RegEX is faster - hands down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to get what you need:

```
^(\w{0,8})\s*(\w+)\s*(\w{3})(\w{3})$
```

This regex will:

1. Match the 0 to 8 word characters from the beginning of the string
2. Followed by 0 or more spaces
3. Followed by 1 or more word characters
4. Followed by 0 or more spaces
5. Followed by 3 word characters
6. Followed by 3 word characters
7. End of string

Word characters (`\w`) are any alphanumeric character, plus the underscore character. If you strictly want only capital letters for instance, you can replace `\w` with a character class of A-Z (any letter in the range A-Z), using `[A-Z]`

[See example](https://regex101.com/r/fB6wZ9/2)

Comment: Check my updated OP... made some additions that may matter to the RegEX.

Comment: for **DEFAULT EP1     O25R60** I test it out in your example and it tells me **Your pattern does not match the subject string.**

Answer (score 2):

If your desire is to actually use regex to split at those positions, you could use the following:

```
Dim s As String = "508815  AYBK1619RAUEZP"
Dim m() As String = Regex.Split(s, "(?<=^.{8})|(?<=^.{16})|(?<=^.{19})")
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", m)) '=> "508815   AYBK1619 RAU EZP"
```

You could also just **match** the substrings at those positions instead of `split`ting ...

```
Dim s As String = "AWBZ4222TYBE1207CWSWER"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s, "^(.{8})(.{8})(.{3})(.{3})$")
If m.Success Then
   Console.WriteLine(
          String.Join(" ", 
                      m.Groups(1).Value,
                      m.Groups(2).Value,
                      m.Groups(3).Value,
                      m.Groups(4).Value
                     ))
End If

'**Output => "AWBZ4222 TYBE1207 CWS WER"
```

Comment: That's another way of doing it as well so thanks for posting that as well, hwnd!